# Why are coinbase transactions locked for 60 blocks?

Tags: blockchain, transaction-unlock-time, mining, coinbase-transaction

"Normal" transactions are locked for 10 blocks [to prevent invalid outputs from being used in ring signatures](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2784/1061).

Why are coinbase transactions (mined coins) locked longer? Are there additional risks linked to those transactions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand, this is to make sure that the coins were mined on the longest blockchain, and thus the longer "delay" of 60 blocks is meant as a safeguard against transactions becoming invalid because of blockchain reorganizations. These might change several dozens of blocks sometimes.

While 60 blocks should typically be enough, I have seen some [larger blockchain reorgs on testnet](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3534/i-have-the-impression-blockchain-reorgs-are-more-prevalent-on-testnet). So, if you were to spend mining rewards of blocks that would later become invalid, that transaction would also be invalidated.