# Upgraded to v0.11.0.0 on MacOS

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, macos

Upgraded from beta 2 to MacOS gui wallet v0.11.0.0 on MacOS 10.12.6.  Saved the old beta 2 config in a safe directory.  Moved the extracted 64bit Mac gui wallet v0.11.0.0 in my application folder.  Started gui and let the blockchain complete syncing.  I'm showing a lock icon to the left of my balance.  The Unlocked balance is showing the full value of the wallet.  Does the Lock icon signify that my balance is locked?  If so, how do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The Unlocked balance is showing the full value of the wallet. Does the Lock icon signify that my balance is locked? If so, how do I fix this?

It sounds like everything is working as designed. *Unlocked* just means that your coins are available for spending. If you were still syncing or if all of your [available outputs were spent <10 blocks ago](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4579/is-the-10-block-lock-time-a-protocol-rule-what-rules-accompany-it) your balance would be locked.